# NextJS13 + Prisma

Tags: typescript, next.js, crud, prisma

I have a problem with fetching data with prisma on NextJS 13.
I would like to fetch some data to map it.

There is my code:

Schema.prisma:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Admin {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  username  String   @unique
  password  String
  email     String   @unique
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Post {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  title      String
  intro      String
  firstText  String   @db.Text
  quote      String
  secondText String   @db.Text
  finalText  String   @db.Text
  createdAt  DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt  DateTime @updatedAt
  images     Image[]  @relation("PostToImage")
}

model Image {
  id    Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  url   String
  posts Post[] @relation("PostToImage")
}

model Region {
  id     Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name   String
  villes Ville[]
}

model Ville {
  id               Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name             String
  startDate        String
  endDate          String
  programStartDate String
  link             String
  regionId         Int
  region           Region @relation(fields: [regionId], references: [id])
}
```

Components:

```
'use client'

import React, { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";

interface Ville {
  name: string;
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
  programStartDate: string;
  link: string;
}

function toClassName(name: string) {
  return name.replace(/ /g, "_");
}

interface Region {
  name: string;
  villes: Ville[];
}

interface Props {
  regions: Region[];
  villes: Ville[];
}

const Candidature: React.FC<Props> = ({ regions, villes }) => {
  const [stage, setStage] = useState<"REGION" | "VILLE" | "JOIN">("REGION");
  const [selectedRegion, setSelectedRegion] = useState<Region | null>(null);
  const [selectedVille, setSelectedVille] = useState<Ville | null>(null);

  const selectRegion = (region: Region) => {
    setSelectedRegion(region);
    setStage("VILLE");
  };

  const selectVille = (ville: Ville) => {
    setSelectedVille(ville);
    setStage("JOIN");
  };

  return (
    <section className={`Section-Candidature ${stage}`}>
      <div className="Choice">
        <button className={stage === "REGION" ? "active" : ""}>CHOISIS TA REGION</button>
          <button className={stage === "VILLE" ? "active" : ""}>CHOISIS TA VILLE</button>
        <button className={stage === "JOIN" ? "active" : ""}>REJOINS NOUS!</button>
      </div>

      {stage === "REGION" && (
        <div className="FrancePays">
          {regions.map((region, index) => (
            <div key={index} className={toClassName(region.name)}>
              <p>{region.name}</p>
              <Image
                src="/SVG/flecheBlanche.svg"
                alt="Entrepreneur souriant"
                width={40} // Width and height must be explicitly given for Next.js Image
                height={40}
                className="Fleches"
                onClick={() => selectRegion(region)}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}

      {stage === "VILLE" && selectedRegion && (
        <div className="FranceRegion">
          {selectedRegion.villes.map((ville, index) => (
            <div key={index} className={toClassName(ville.name)}>
              <p>{ville.name}</p>
              <Image
                src="/SVG/flecheBlanche.svg"
                alt="Entrepreneur souriant"
                width={40} // Width and height must be explicitly given for Next.js Image
                height={40}
                className="Fleches"
                onClick={() => selectVille(ville)}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}

      {stage === "JOIN" && selectedVille && (
        <div className="Join">
          <div className="TroisSemaines">
            <p>3</p>
            <p>SEMAINES DE FORMATION INTENSIVE</p>
          </div>
          <div className="CinqMois"><p>5</p>
            <p>MOIS D&apos;ACCOMPAGNEMENT</p></div>
          <div className="Annee">
            <p>
            DECOUVRE LA PROMO 2023
            </p>
            <Image
                  src='/assets/Annee.png'
                  alt='Determines'
                  fill
                  objectFit='cover'
                  placeholder="blur"
                  blurDataURL={'/assets/Annee.png'}
                  className='Determines'
                />
            </div>
          <div className="Debut">
            <p>{selectedVille.startDate}</p>
            <p>DEBUT APPEL CANDIDATURE</p>
            </div>
          <div className="Fin">
            <p>{selectedVille.endDate}</p>
            <p>FIN APPEL CANDIDATURE</p>
            </div>
          <div className="Formation">
            <p>{selectedVille.programStartDate}</p>
            <p>FORMATION INTENSIVE DE 6 MOIS</p>
            </div>
          <div className="Lien">
            <p>JE POSTULE</p>
            <Link href={selectedVille.link} target="_blank" >
                    <Image
                      src='/SVG/flecheBlanche.svg'
                      alt='Entrepreneur souriant'
                      fill
                      objectFit='contain'
                      placeholder="blur"
                      blurDataURL={'/public/SVG/fleche.svg'}
                      className='Fleches'
                    />
                    </Link>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      )}
    
    </section>
  );
};

export default Candidature;

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<Props> = async () => {
  try {
    const [regionsResponse, villesResponse] = await Promise.all([
      fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/regions"),
      fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/villes"), // Assurez-vous d'avoir une route pour les villes
      console.log("OK")
    ]);

    const [regions, villes] = await Promise.all([
      regionsResponse.json(),
      villesResponse.json(),
    ]);

    return {
      props: {
        regions,
        villes,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    return {
      props: {
        regions: [],
        villes: [],
      },
    };
  }
};
```

api/regions:

```
import type { NextApiResponse } from "next";

import prismadb from "@/lib/prismadb";// Assurez-vous d'importer prisma correctement

export async function GET(req: Request, res: NextApiResponse) {

 try {
   const regions = await prismadb.region.findMany({
     include: { villes: true },
   });
   return req
 } catch (error) {
   console.error('Error fetching regions:', error);
 }
}
```

I'm struggling to get the data, it send me an error 500.
I would like to have my regions and my city to map them in my code, everything is ready on the databases.

Comment: Can you share with us the error message you see on the terminal console?

Comment: Getting the error stack trace would indeed be helpful to debug this